# Azure RDP requires certificate installed on client machine?

Tags: azure

On a project I’m working on at my current job, we need to enable the RDP on azure web role. I've enabled the RDP but client is not being able to connect. We confirmed RDP port is opened as well.

Doesn't client needs to install certificate on his/her machine as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the client doesn't need to install a certificate on their machine. When you deploy a cloud service from Azure you can opt to have an RDP account created at the point of deployment, this will automatically configure the endpoints for 3389 on the instance. Are you sure the client is using the correct case on the password and has their firewall open on 3389?

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify how would the connection be authenticated and secured without having to install Certificate on client.

Comment: By default an RDP connection is SSL encrypted with a self signed cert. you should receive a warning on your initial connection. You can use a signed cert if paranoid.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not. If you're having problems try to download the assistant file that will set up everything BUT your firewall, leaving you to just hit "Connect"